# Where do the following words come from: лето, весна, осень, зима?

Tags: этимология

I am interested in knowing the etymology of names of the seasons in Russian: лето, весна, осень, зима.

**UPDATE:**

And especially the original meaning of the proto-words that gave birth to these words.

Comment: Proto-words in which language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proto-Slavic ancestors of these words (see Armen's answer) meant, surprisingly enough, summer, spring, fall and winter, accordingly :)

Tracing the meanings back to PIE would be a little bit harder, since it's relatively easy to reconstruct phonetics of the roots but not their exact semantics.

According to Vasmer and Chernykh:

- *Весна* from PIE `*wesr-/*wesn-`, "spring" (akin to English *vernal*)
- *Лето* from PIE `*lē-`, "to allow, to let, to loosen" (akin to English *let*)
- *Осень* from PIE `*esen-`, "to harvest" (akin to English *earn*)
- *Зима* from PIE `*gheim-`, "snow, winter" (akin to English *hibernate*)

Answer (score 3):

[Из викисловаря](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0):

- **лето**

> Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. лѣто (др.-греч. χρόνος, ἔτος, ἐνιαυτός), русск. лето, укр. лíто, белор. сле́цiць «согреть», сле́тный «тепловатый», смол., болг. ля́то, сербохорв. ље̏то, словенск. lẹ́to, чешск. léto, словацк. lеtо, польск. lаtо, в.-луж., н.-луж. lěto

- **весна**

> Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск., ст.-слав. весна (др.-греч. ἔαρ), русск., укр. весна́, сербохорв. вѐсна, словенск. vȇsna, чешск. vesna, польск. wiosna. Древняя и.-е. основа на r/n, ср. лит. vasarà «лето», латышск. vasara, греч. ἔαρ, лат. vēr, др.-исл. vár «весна», др.-инд. vasantás «весна», vasar «рано», авест. vaŋri- «весной», арм. գարուն/garun/ «весна»

- **осень**

> Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. осень, ср.: сербск.-церк.-слав. ıесень (др.-греч. φθινόπωρον, укр. о́сінь (род. п. о́сени), болг. есента́, сербохорв. jе̏се̑н, до̏ jесени, словенск. jesȇn, чешск. jeseň, словацк. jeseň, польск. jesień. Родственно др.-прусск. assanis «осень», готск. аsаns ж. «жатва», др.-в.-нем. аrаn, аrn «урожай». Далее сближают с греч. ὀπώρᾱ «конец лета, жатва» из *ор᾽ + оsаrā «после жатвы». Сюда же есене́сь «прошлой осенью», с.-в.-р., вост.-русск., осеня́сь со стар. вин. ед. от сь (см. сей), др.-русск. осеньсь, болг. есене́с, сербохорв. jесѐнас, словенск. jesȇnǝs — то же

- **зима**

> Происходит от праслав. формы *zīmā, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск., ст.-слав. зима (др.-греч. χεῖμών), русск., укр. зима́, болг. зи́ма, сербохорв. зи́ма (вин. зи̑му), словенск. zíma, чешск., словацк., польск. zima, н.-луж., в.-луж. zуmа. Из праиндоевр. *g'heim-, родственно лит. žiemà (вин. žiẽmą) «зима», латышск. zìema — то же, др.-прусск. semo — то же, др.-инд. hḗman «зимой», himás «зима», hēmantás — то же, авест. zyå-(zim-), zimō «мороз, зима», греч. χεῖμα «зима», χειμών «зимняя буря», χειμερινός «зимний», алб.-гег. dimën, тоск. dimër «зима», лат. hiems «зима», bīmus (*bihimos) «двухлетний», hībernus «зимний», датск. диал. gimmerlam «годовалый ягненок», арм. ձմեռ/dzmer/ «зима». Соболевский хочет видеть в нар. зи́мусь «этой зимой», др.-русск. зимусь (грам. ок. 1300 г.), болг. зимъс, сербохорв. зи́му̑с древний вин. п. ед. ч. -сь основы на -i. Гадательно.

Nothing interesting, if you ask me...

Comment: Armen can you please provide a translation of your answer into English since the original question is in English? (See http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/92/should-we-discourage-explanation-in-russian-in-answer-to-questions-in-english)

Comment: question was rather the original meaning of these words, not the morphology, but I still appreciate your answer

Comment: @Lisa: The meta discussion ended in a consensus that we shall not force translations

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Nevertheless it would still be a nice thing to do to make your answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

- **Осень** - from PIE ***e̯eson*** - "harvest"
- ***Зима*** - from PIE ***ĝhi̯om*** - "frost, snowy weather"
- ***Весна*** - from PIE ***u̯esr*** - "spring"
- ***Лето*** - etymology is unknown (there is a lot of conjectures).